# New TabItem at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

Hi I am using TabControl to make Conference System, the private chats would be in a new TabItem. I am using this code to present a new member chatting in private:

```
TabItem ti = new TabItem();
ti.Header="Name";
MyTabControl.Items.Add(ti);
```

but the problem with this code is that I am adding a list box in the TabItem but the TabItem doesn't have a function to add an item in it. how can I add items into TabItem?

Second try: I used this code to present a new member chatting in private

```
ItemsControl it = new ItemsControl();
ListBox lst = new ListBox();
lst.Width = 571;
lst.Height = 301;

it.Items.Add(lst);
tabControlChat.Items.Add(it);
```

with this code I can add all items I need in the new tab. but the main problem is that I can't name the tab there is no property like (ti.Header) to name the tab. so what is the solution please? and thank you

Comment: You don't really want to write code like this in WPF, look into [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
    TabItem ti = new TabItem();
    ti.Header = "Name";
    tabControl1.Items.Add(ti);

    ListBox lst = new ListBox();
    lst.Width = 571;
    lst.Height = 301;

    ti.Content = lst;
```

Comment: where can I add my new listBox?

Comment: If I helped you, don't forget to mark my answer as a good answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

For short:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
lb.Items.Add("chat member");

TabItem ti = new TabItem();
ti.Header = "Private Chats";
ti.Content = lb;

TabControl tc = new TabControl();
tc.Items.Add(ti);
```